# How can I send a random image?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to post a random dog picture when someone says `toggledoggo`. Every time I try to run the command, it gives me an error message in the terminal, and does nothing.

Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", message => {
  var prefix = 'toggle';
  var doggos = ['dog1', 'dog2'];
  var dog1 = message.channel.send({ files: ['dog1.jpg'] });
  var dog2 = message.channel.send({ files: ['dog2.jpg'] });
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'doggo')) {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * doggos.length);
  };
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: Can you tell us the error that the terminal shows you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a truly random picture (pseudo-random but still) use an api. I use dog.ceo. Heres a code that, while big, gives a user plenty of options to choose from.

```
if(msg.split(' ')[0] === prefix + "doggo"){
    let breeds = []; // Initializing an array to use later
    let breeds2 = []; // Due to the size, we need to split it.
    request('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all', async function (error, response, body) { // Begin a request to list all breeds.
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
            for(var name in importedJSON.message){ // looping through every breed and pushing it into the array made earlier
                breeds.push(name)
                if(importedJSON.message[name].length != 0){
                    for(var i = 0; i < importedJSON.message[name].length; i++){
                        breeds.push("- " + importedJSON.message[name][i]) // Pushing sub-breeds into the array too
                    }
                }
            }
            for(var j = 0; j < breeds.length/2; j++){ // Halving the previous array because it's too big for one message.
                let toArray = breeds.shift()
                breeds2.push(toArray)
            }
        }
    })
    let args = msg.split(' ').slice(1)
    if(!args[0]){ // if no breed, then send a random image
        request('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random', async function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                return await message.channel.send(importedJSON.message)
            }
        })
    }
    if(args[0] === "breeds"){ // Command to list the breeds.
        setTimeout(async function(){
            let m = breeds2.map(name => name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)) // Creating a map of the arrays earlier to send as a message
            let m2 = breeds.map(name => name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1))
            await message.channel.send(m)
            return await message.channel.send(m2)
        }, 1000);
    }
    if(args[0]){
        setTimeout(async function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < breeds.length; i++){ // Looping through every breed in the array to see if it matches the input
                if(args[0] == breeds[i]){ 
                    let input = breeds[i]
                    args.shift() // This is to check for a sub breed input, which is taken into account in the else statement of this if statement
                    if(!args[0] || args[0] == undefined){
                        request(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${input}/images/random`, async function (error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                                return await message.channel.send(importedJSON.message)
                            }else{
                                await message.channel.send(`You must have typed something wrong, do ${prefix}doggo breeds for a list of breeds.`)
                                return
                            }
                        })
                        return
                    }else{
                        request(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${input}/${args[0]}/images/random`, async function (error, response, body) { // requesting a dog of a certain breed and sub breed
                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                                return await message.channel.send(importedJSON.message)
                            }else{
                                await message.channel.send(`You must have typed something wrong, do ${prefix}doggo breeds for a list of breeds.`)
                                return
                            }
                        })
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < breeds2.length; i++){ // This is identical to the above, but with the other array
                if(args[0] == breeds2[i]){
                    let input = breeds2[i]
                    args.shift()
                    if(!args[0] || args[0] == undefined){
                        request(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${input}/images/random`, async function (error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                                return await message.channel.send(importedJSON.message)
                            }else{
                                await message.channel.send(`You must have typed something wrong, do ${prefix}doggo breeds for a list of breeds.`)
                                return
                            }
                        })
                        return
                    }else{
                        request(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${input}/${args[0]}/images/random`, async function (error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                                var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                                return await message.channel.send(importedJSON.message)
                            }else{
                                await message.channel.send(`You must have typed something wrong, do ${prefix}doggo breeds for a list of breeds.`)
                                return
                            }
                        })
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
};
```

The acceptable command for this are: (prefix)doggo, (prefix)doggo breeds, (prefix)doggo (breed), (prefix)doggo (breed) (sub breed)
You will need the "request" module you can read up on it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request. Hopefully the comments I put in the code are enough to explain whats going on if not, ask for clarification. If you just wanted a small command for 2 pictures then you can also tell me and I'll delete this post entirely.